# Validation error detected at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I am using aws-api-gateway-cli-test to test API gateway. API is authenticated via cognito user pool, i am getting the error:

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'eu-central-1_xxxxxxxx' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+
```

I am not sure which value to use for identityPoolId. Where can i get this information.

Trying the ARN like `arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:userpool/eu-central-1_xxxxxxxxxx` failed. Pool Id in format `eu-central-1_xxxxxxxxxx` also failed.

Example usage:

```
npx aws-api-gateway-cli-test \
--username='user' \
--password='password' \
--user-pool-id='eu-central-1_xxxxxxx' \
--app-client-id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--cognito-region='eu-central-1' \
--identity-pool-id='eu-central-1_xxxxxxxx' \
--invoke-url='https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/' \
--api-gateway-region='eu-central-1' \
--path-template='/xxxx/xxxxx' \
--method='POST' \
--body='{"foo":"bar","lorem":"ipsum"}'
```

resulted in

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'eu-central-1_xxxxxxx' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+
```

According to:
https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/aws-api-gateway-cli-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find identity pool id by going to Identity pool, selecting your identity pool and then clicking on edit identity pool.
[image]

Your Identity pool will be in the format:

> us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx